# Android - Spinner not spinning. Spinner freezed

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialog

I have a progressDialog. The spinner in the progressDialog has to spin and it should not allow the user to do anything. But the spinner is not working the properly. It is getting freezed and it goes to the next activity. Could you please assit me to resolve this ?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bNewTicket:    
        // custom dialog 
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.homepagedialognewticket, null);
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);   

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { 
                    EditText etTableNumber,etGuestCount;  
                    etTableNumber = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etTableNumber);
                    etGuestCount  = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etGuestCount);
                    tableNumber = etTableNumber.getText().toString();
                    guestCount  = etGuestCount.getText().toString();  
                    if ( tableNumber.isEmpty() || guestCount.isEmpty() ) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
                        d.setTitle("Alert  ");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                        tv.setText("Table # and Guest # are mandatory ");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    } else{ 
                        dialog.cancel(); 
                        runDialog();
                        }
                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("Back",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { 
                dialog.cancel();
                }
              });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
        alertDialog.show();  
        break;   
    }       
} 

private void createNewTicket() {
        try {  

            Terminal terminal;
            terminal = PosClient.getTerminal(85);
            Ticket ticket = PosClient.createTicket(Integer.valueOf(tableNumber), Integer.valueOf(guestCount), terminal, ((User) basket.getSerializable("user")));
            Intent i = new Intent(HomePage.this,NewTicket.class);   
            basket.putSerializable("ticket", ticket);
            i.putExtras(basket);
            startActivity(i);   
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    } 

private void runDialog()
    { 
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...." , "Menu is loading");

        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ 

            createNewTicket(); 
                progressDialog.dismiss(); 
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: In your runDialog(), what background process you are running. It seems you are dismissing it as soon as you start it.

Comment: Appu , I have edited the code..

Comment: Try putting this progressDialog.setCancelable(true); after the first line in your runDialog() method.

Comment: I added progressDialog.setCancelable(true); .  still the same. The spinner is getting started and freezed

Comment: Try adding finish() after these lines i.putExtras(basket);startActivity(i);   If you still don't get then make use of asynctask.

Comment: Thanks I used AsynchhTask

Comment: Glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the createNewTicket function to async task.

In your code all the tasks are running on the main thread. The layout changes will take effect only when the main thread stops execution.